# Find all time (H:i) strings on page and convert to UTC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have website that has different tables with some `H:i` time strings that are in specific local time.

Is it possible to use JavaScript or jQuery to search all time strings on web page and convert them to UTC time, lets say I know the time difference with local and UTC is -3 hours.

I am thinking of some loop and regex to find `H:i`  and then some math, but not sure how to put it together.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I have put something together, but obviously this does not work yet, due to lack of knowledge.

```js
$.each($('td'), function() {
  var regex = new RegExp('/^(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/');
  var string = $(this).text();
  if (regex.test(string)) {
    alert('found: ' + string); //FOR TESTING
    //DO SOMETHING TO CONVERT TIME TO UTC
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:01</td>
    <td>random text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla</td>
    <td>23:47</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find time by `RegExp` pattern `'^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$'` and recommend you to use `moment.js` to convert yout time to `UTC`

```js
$.each($('td'), function() {
  var regex = new RegExp('^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$');
  var string = $(this).text();
  if (regex.test(string)) {
    console.log('found: ' + string);

    let m = moment(string, "HH:mm").utc().format("HH:mm")
    $(this).text(m)
   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>08:01</td>
    <td>random text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bla</td>
    <td>23:47</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it dynamically and add the changes to table.

```js
$('table td').each(function(){
            var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(this.innerHTML);
            let UTC = 3;
            if(isValid){
               let splitted = this.innerHTML.split(':');
               //subtract to hours UTC (-3).
               let hours = (splitted[0] < UTC) ? UTC - splitted[0] : splitted[0] - UTC;
               if(hours.toString().length == 1){
                  hours = "0"+hours;
               }
               let min = splitted[1];

               this.innerHTML = hours+":"+min;
            }
             
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>
          <th>Header</th>
          <th>Header2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>08:01</td>
          <td>random text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bla</td>
          <td>23:47</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```